# Select only certain raws from an sql query

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to collect the highest mountain for each country on the American continent from this database : http://www.semwebtech.org/sqlfrontend/

When I execute this query :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Country.Name AS Country, Mountain.Name AS Mountain, Elevation FROM Mountain
JOIN Geo_Mountain ON Mountain=Name
JOIN Encompasses ON Geo_Mountain.Country=Encompasses.Country 
JOIN Country ON Geo_Mountain.Country=Country.Code

WHERE Continent='North America' OR Continent='South America'
ORDER BY Country.Name, Elevation DESC
```

This is an extract of what I have :

```
COUNTRY     MOUNTAIN        ELEVATION
Argentina   Aconcagua           6962 
Argentina   Ojos del Salado     6893 
Argentina   Monte Pissis        6795 
Bolivia     Alto Toroni         5982 
Bolivia     Licancabur          5920 
Bolivia     Ollagüe             5870 
Bolivia     Zapaleri            5653
```

The thing is that I have all the mountain listed in the database and I'm unable to select only the highest mountain for each country

I'v tried to use `GROUP BY Country.Name` between `WHERE`and `ORDER BY`but received and error message:

> A database error occured: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Here is the Referential Dependencies Diagramm: http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-abh.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group by country.name` is correct. But you must make more changes. In the `select` clause, you can select `country.name` since you are grouping by it. So far so good.

`elevation` can't stand, and it is not what you want - you want `max(elevation) as elevation`. You only want the `max` for each group.

The more interesting is the mountain name. Of course, it is not a group function; but you don't want that. You only want the name of the highest mountain in each group (that is, in each country). There are a few ways to do that; the most efficient is

```
max(mountain.name) keep (dense_rank last order by elevation) as mountain_name
```

Comment: This works really fine, but I can't show the elevation (which is not required but I'd like to have it).
When I try to add `,Elevation` after your command, I once again received the error message `not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: @AlistairLucet - Please read my answer again, all of it. Do you see where your question is addressed already?